# add image in email with flutter_email_sender

Tags: flutter, dart, email, base64

I am creating an Android application with flutter/dart and I want to send an email with an embedded image inside.

So I installed flutter_email_sender and tried to use it. It works to send an email with text, but when I tried to add an image. It doesn't appear in the email application.

Here is my code:

```dart
// DataUser.pathImage is the path of the image (/data/src/0/cache/hi.jpg)
// extension(DataUser.pathImage).substring(1) => "jpg"
// DataUser.emailText.split("\n").join("<br>") is the text of the user that will be send
//                ex: "Hi\nYes\nNo" => "Hi<br>Yes<br>No"
final bytes = File(DataUser.pathImage).readAsBytesSync();
String image64 = base64.encode(bytes);
String result = "<p>" + DataUser.emailText.split("\n").join("<br>") + "<br>";
result += "<img src=\"data:image/${extension(DataUser.pathImage).substring(1)};base64," + image64;
result += "\" alt=\"image\" />";
result += "</p>";

final Email email = Email(
    body: result,
    subject: "Pointage",
    recipients: DataUser.adresse,
    attachmentPaths: DataUser.filePath, 
    isHTML: true,
);

await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
```

Is there a way to send an email containing an image with this extension?

Answer (score 0):

In Email object, *attachmentPaths* accepts list of file paths i.e. List. You can check the complete example [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender/example).

Create a list of strings for attachments file paths:

```
  List<String> attachments = [];
```

Now add your image path (string) to this list.

(I think you are doing a mistake by adding .readAsBytesSync(), I don't think that's necessary).

Let's say user picks an image from gallery:

```
    PickedFile? pick = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pick != null) {
      setState(() {
        attachments.add(pick.path); //this line adds file path to attachments
      });
    }
```

Now pass this attachments list to the Email object.

```
Email(
    body: result,
    subject: "Pointage",
    recipients: DataUser.adresse,
    attachmentPaths: attachments,
    isHTML: true,
);
```